# What is the encoding problem when Calling R from Proc IML

Tags: sas

When I call R from Proc IML, it reports an ERROR: SAS is unable to transcode character data to the R encoding

I submit this line of code : `%put %sysfunc(getoption(encoding));`
the result is *`UTF-8`*

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese       
    (Simplified)_China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C"
```

The following is the example codes from SAS document:
proc options option=rlang;
run;

```
RLANG             Enables SAS to execute R language statements.
NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTIONS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

 option set=R_HOME='C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2';

   proc iml;
      
   x = 1:3;
                                     /* vector of sequence 1,2,3 */
   m = {1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9};
                                    /* 3 x 3 matrix */
   q = m * t(x);
                                 /* matrix multiplication */

   submit / R;
     rx <- matrix( 1:3, nrow=1)             # vector of sequence 1,2,3
     rm <- matrix( 1:9, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE) # 3 x 3 matrix
     rq <- rm %*% t(rx)                     # matrix multiplication
 
   endsubmit;
 quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message. The R version `4.0.3` was not compatible with the SAS ver `9.4`
that I was running on a `windows 1`0.

https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/09/16/what-versions-of-r-are-supported-by-sas.html

The problem was resolved with R version `3.6.3`. Included the following code to point to the compatible version of R.

```
 options set=R_HOME='C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3';
```